# Learn more about CocoaPods

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I am developing with Xcode and I use Swift.
I want to learn more about Cocoapods. Where, how and what does it allow to do ? 
How to install it (if it is not already present in Xcode)?
Thank you in advance !

Comment: Please read apple [Cocoa Touch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Cocoa.html), or for more in depth on both platform read [Defining Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html)

Comment: there is a relation CocoaPod?

Comment: CocoaPods is the dependency manager for Swift and Objective-C Cocoa projects. It has over ten thousand libraries and can help you scale your projects elegantly. read please. https://cocoapods.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading your comment, I think you mean to use CocoaPods.

CocoaPods is a dependency-manager for Xcode. Allows you to easily integrate other frameworks into your projects. It does not come pre-installed with MacOS or XCode. In order to use CocoaPods with your Xcode projects, start a new Terminal window and execute the command:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

This command will get your system ready to use CocoaPods.

Then go to your project folder

```
cd ~/Path/To/Folder/Containing/Project
```

and run the following command to create a new Podfile within that project:

```
pod init
```

Afterwards, edit the Podfile in Xcode by executing the command:

```
open -a Xcode Podfile
```

and add, in the first target, the dependencies, for example:

```
pod 'Alamofire', '1.2.3'
```

If you are developing in Swift, then also change the beginning (top) to:

```
platform :ios, "8.0"
use_frameworks!
```

Save and exit Xcode. Go back to the Terminal window and run the command to setup the dependecies:

```
pod install
```

Done! You now should have a workspace file created in the same folder. Use that file to load the project and code away.

This is all better explained at http://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift